# Sorting and ranking by dates, on a group in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by, ranking

From the following sort of dataframe I would like to be able to both sort and rank the `id` field on date:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id':[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6,6,6,7,7], 
'value':[.01, .4, .2, .3, .11, .21, .4, .01, 3, .5, .8, .9],
'date':['10/01/2017 15:45:00','05/01/2017 15:56:00',
        '11/01/2017 15:22:00','06/01/2017 11:02:00','05/01/2017 09:37:00',
        '05/01/2017 09:55:00','05/01/2017 10:08:00','03/02/2017 08:55:00',
        '03/02/2017 09:15:00','03/02/2017 09:31:00','09/01/2017 15:42:00',
        '19/01/2017 16:34:00']})
```

to effectively rank or index, per `id`, based on date.

I've used

```
df.groupby('id')['date'].min()
```

which allows me to extract the first date (although I don't know how to use this to filter out the rows) but I might not always need the first date - sometimes it will be the second or third so I need to generate a new column, with an index for the date - the result would look like:

[image]

Any ideas on this sorting/ranking/labelling?

### EDIT

My original model ignored a very prevalent issue.

As there are feasibly some `id`s that have multiple tests performed on them in parallel, therefore they show in multiple rows in the datebase, with matching dates (`date` corresponds to when they were logged). These should be counted as the same date and not increment the date_rank: I've generated a model, with updated `date_rank` to demonstrate how this would look:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6,6,6,7,7], 
'value':[.01, .4, .5, .7, .77, .1,.2, 0.3, .11, .21, .4, .01, 3, .5, .8, .9, .1],
'date':['10/01/2017 15:45:00','10/01/2017 15:45:00','05/01/2017 15:56:00',
        '11/01/2017 15:22:00','11/01/2017 15:22:00','06/01/2017 11:02:00','05/01/2017 09:37:00','05/01/2017 09:37:00','05/01/2017 09:55:00',
        '05/01/2017 09:55:00','05/01/2017 10:08:00','05/01/2017 10:09:00','03/02/2017 08:55:00',
        '03/02/2017 09:15:00','03/02/2017 09:31:00','09/01/2017 15:42:00',
        '19/01/2017 16:34:00']})
```

And the counter would afford this:

[image]

Comment: The question seems unclear. `I might not always need the first date`. So what's the logic?

Comment: Sorry it's unclear - I need to count the dates per id, so the first date (of test) of the id is 1, second test date is 2, etc, and have that tracked in a column, so (for example) I can quickly pull the second set of test data. This table is actually 100000's lines long, and there are up to 20 repeat tests (as an aside, the test can affect the result, which needs tracking)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try of sorting date values in descending and aggregating the 'id' group values

@praveen's logic is very simpler, by extending of logic, you can use astype of category to convert the values to categories and can retrive the codes (keys') of that categories, but it will be little bit different to your expected output

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['id', 'date'], ascending=[True, False])
df1['date_rank'] =df1.groupby(['id']).apply(lambda x: x['date'].astype('category',ordered=False).cat.codes+1).values
```

Out:

```
                 date   id  value   date_rank
0   10/01/2017 15:45:00 1   0.01    2
1   10/01/2017 15:45:00 1   0.40    2
2   05/01/2017 15:56:00 1   0.50    1
3   11/01/2017 15:22:00 2   0.70    1
4   11/01/2017 15:22:00 2   0.77    1
5   06/01/2017 11:02:00 3   0.10    2
6   05/01/2017 09:37:00 3   0.20    1
7   05/01/2017 09:37:00 3   0.30    1
8   05/01/2017 09:55:00 4   0.11    1
9   05/01/2017 09:55:00 4   0.21    1
11  05/01/2017 10:09:00 5   0.01    2
10  05/01/2017 10:08:00 5   0.40    1
14  03/02/2017 09:31:00 6   0.80    3
13  03/02/2017 09:15:00 6   0.50    2
12  03/02/2017 08:55:00 6   3.00    1
16  19/01/2017 16:34:00 7   0.10    2
15  09/01/2017 15:42:00 7   0.90    1
```

but to get your exact output, here i have used dictionary and reversing dictionary keys with extracting values

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['id', 'date'], ascending=[True, False])
df1['date_rank'] = df1.groupby(['id'])['date'].transform(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: dict(map(reversed, dict(enumerate(x.unique())).items()))[y]+1,x)) )
```

Out:

```
                date    id  value   date_rank
0   10/01/2017 15:45:00 1   0.01    1
1   10/01/2017 15:45:00 1   0.40    1
2   05/01/2017 15:56:00 1   0.50    2
3   11/01/2017 15:22:00 2   0.70    1
4   11/01/2017 15:22:00 2   0.77    1
5   06/01/2017 11:02:00 3   0.10    1
6   05/01/2017 09:37:00 3   0.20    2
7   05/01/2017 09:37:00 3   0.30    2
8   05/01/2017 09:55:00 4   0.11    1
9   05/01/2017 09:55:00 4   0.21    1
11  05/01/2017 10:09:00 5   0.01    1
10  05/01/2017 10:08:00 5   0.40    2
14  03/02/2017 09:31:00 6   0.80    1
13  03/02/2017 09:15:00 6   0.50    2
12  03/02/2017 08:55:00 6   3.00    3
16  19/01/2017 16:34:00 7   0.10    1
15  09/01/2017 15:42:00 7   0.90    2
```

Comment: I've just made an edit to the original que: unfortunately neither response can account for the (likely) possibility of multiple entries for the same date, and them being ranked the same - do you think your answer could be modified to take this in to account? There is a new dataset, with desired output, above. Cheers

Comment: Thanks - that works. It's 100k+ rows and took no time, too.I tried to get somewhere with mapping, but was miles away. THanks again

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by sort_values, groupby and [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount)

```
df['date_rank'] = df.sort_values(['id', 'date'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby(['id']).cumcount() + 1
```

*demo*

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({
    ...: 'id':[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6,6,6,7,7],
    ...: 'value':[.01, .4, .2, .3, .11, .21, .4, .01, 3, .5, .8, .9],
    ...: 'date':['10/01/2017 15:45:00','05/01/2017 15:56:00',
    ...:         '11/01/2017 15:22:00','06/01/2017 11:02:00','05/01/2017 09:37:00',
    ...:         '05/01/2017 09:55:00','05/01/2017 10:08:00','03/02/2017 08:55:00',
    ...:         '03/02/2017 09:15:00','03/02/2017 09:31:00','09/01/2017 15:42:00',
    ...:         '19/01/2017 16:34:00']})
    ...:

In [2]: df['date_rank'] = df.sort_values(['id', 'date'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby(['id']).cumcount() + 1
    ...:

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
    id  value                 date  date_rank
0    1   0.01  10/01/2017 15:45:00          1
1    1   0.40  05/01/2017 15:56:00          2
2    2   0.20  11/01/2017 15:22:00          1
3    3   0.30  06/01/2017 11:02:00          1
4    3   0.11  05/01/2017 09:37:00          2
5    4   0.21  05/01/2017 09:55:00          1
6    5   0.40  05/01/2017 10:08:00          1
7    6   0.01  03/02/2017 08:55:00          3
8    6   3.00  03/02/2017 09:15:00          2
9    6   0.50  03/02/2017 09:31:00          1
10   7   0.80  09/01/2017 15:42:00          2
11   7   0.90  19/01/2017 16:34:00          1
```

**Edit**

you can do this by rank method

```
df.groupby(['id'])['date'].rank(ascending=False, method='dense').astype(int)
```

*demo*

```
In [1]: df['rank'] = df.groupby(['id'])['date'].rank(ascending=False, method='dense').astype(int)

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
    id  value                date  rank
0    1   0.01 2017-10-01 15:45:00     1
1    1   0.40 2017-10-01 15:45:00     1
2    1   0.50 2017-05-01 15:56:00     2
3    2   0.70 2017-11-01 15:22:00     1
4    2   0.77 2017-11-01 15:22:00     1
5    3   0.10 2017-06-01 11:02:00     1
6    3   0.20 2017-05-01 09:37:00     2
7    3   0.30 2017-05-01 09:37:00     2
8    4   0.11 2017-05-01 09:55:00     1
9    4   0.21 2017-05-01 09:55:00     1
10   5   0.40 2017-05-01 10:08:00     2
11   5   0.01 2017-05-01 10:09:00     1
12   6   3.00 2017-03-02 08:55:00     3
13   6   0.50 2017-03-02 09:15:00     2
14   6   0.80 2017-03-02 09:31:00     1
15   7   0.90 2017-09-01 15:42:00     1
16   7   0.10 2017-01-19 16:34:00     2
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've accepted this as the answer because whilst it's a one liner i actually find a bit more readable than the other answer - but also as it doesn't generate the rank as a float. Thanks again

Comment: My fault for not writing a robust model dataset - but can this be modified for systems where the same date may be recorded against an id?

Comment: If you can provide some sample data that cover all your cases and expected output, I can modify the solution.

Comment: I will do that now and i'll add it as an Edit in the question. Thanks again

Comment: OK, i've added the edit, an updated model, and an image of the expected output. Thanks