# Pandas how can I locate group n in a sorted groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a massive Pandas dataframe converted to a tensor for deep learning. Now I want to access group n in both my dataframe and my array.

E.g., how do I access the dataframe group that eventually becomes group 3 in the array, with a given set of sorting keys?

On a large dataset, converting the dataframe to an array is *very* slow, as there's roughly 200k groups in millions of rows. So this can only be done once, and not on the fly, and I don't have pickles of lists of groups.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({"a"     : np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
                   "index1": np.random.randint(0, 5, 100),
                   "index2": np.random.randint(0, 5, 100)})

grouped_df = df.groupby(["index1", "index2"])

# convert dataframe to array for e.g. deep learning but never do this operation again (too slow)
array = np.array([group["a"].values for _, group in grouped_df])

# fetch the same sample from the array and the df
array_n = array[3] # this is trivial

# how can I do this in my df?
# grouped_df[3] obviously doesn't work.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [groupby to return nth group - NOT row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53066627/groupby-to-return-nth-group-not-row)

Comment: How about transforming your array back into a dataframe? `d = pd.DataFrame(array)`

Comment: @bwc OP is trying to avoid the intermediate step of turning the dataframe into an array: "On a large dataset, converting the dataframe to an array is very slow"

Comment: What does your data look like (the format)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of group keys using [`grouped_df.groups`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups) attribute, which returns a dict. Then get the keys of that dict using the `keys()` function:

```
In [27]: grouped_df.groups.keys()
Out[27]: dict_keys([(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)])
```

(These keys have values of `(index1, index2)` corresponding to the index1/index2 value for that group.)

The list comprehension you use to populate `array` will iterate through these group keys in order, so element 4 of the resulting array corresponds to the fourth key:

```
In [28]: list(grouped_df.groups.keys())[3]
Out[28]: (0, 3)
```

(which indicates `index1=0` and `index2=3`). Now you can assign that key to a variable and get the group corresponding to that key using the [`grouped_df.get_group()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group) method:

```
In [29]: my_key = list(grouped_df.groups.keys())[3]

In [30]: grouped_df.get_group(my_key)
Out[30]:
           a  index1  index2
0   1.764052       0       3
14  0.443863       0       3
56  0.066517       0       3
58 -0.634322       0       3
65 -0.401781       0       3
69  0.051945       0       3
```

Finally, grab column "a" from the result, and get the values the same way you did with the list comprehension:

```
In [31]: grouped_df.get_group(my_key)['a'].values
Out[31]:
array([ 1.76405235,  0.44386323,  0.06651722, -0.63432209, -0.40178094,
        0.0519454 ])
```

Or, as a somewhat messy one-liner,

```
In [32]: grouped_df.get_group(list(grouped_df.groups.keys())[3])['a'].values
Out[32]:
array([ 1.76405235,  0.44386323,  0.06651722, -0.63432209, -0.40178094,
        0.0519454 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make the groupby lists like so:

```
grouped_df.agg(list).to_numpy().tolist()[3]
```

output:

```
[[1.764052345967664,
  0.44386323274542566,
  0.06651722238316789,
  -0.6343220936809636,
  -0.4017809362082619,
  0.05194539579613895]]
```

Comment: From OP: "On a large dataset, converting the dataframe to an array is very slow" - calling `.to_numpy()` would still incur that overhead cost